# Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-typescript, react-tsx

I cannot get the total because of the type of calculateTotal function

```
import CartItem from "./CartItem"
import {CartItemType} from '../App'
import {Typography,Stack} from '@mui/material';
type Props ={
    cartItem:CartItemType[];
    addToCart:(clickedItem: CartItemType)=>void;
    removeFromCart:(id:number) => void;
}
const Cart: React.FC<Props> = ({cartItem,addToCart,removeFromCart}) => {
  const calculateTotal=(items: CartItemType[])=>{
    items.reduce((ack:number,item)=>ack + item.amount* item.price, 0)
  }
  return (
    <Stack sx={{width:'25em'}}>
        <h4>Your Shopping Cart</h4>
        {cartItem.length ===0? <p>No items in cart.</p>: null}
        {cartItem.map(item=>(

        <CartItem key={item.id} item={item} addToCart={addToCart} removeFromCart={removeFromCart}/>
        ))}
        {/* Total */}
        <p>Total: ${calculateTotal(cartItem)}</p>
    </Stack>
  )
}

export default Cart
```

The calculateTotal function does not work couse it's type

and that's the error messege

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'
> This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the value from `calculateTotal` function

```
const calculateTotal=(items: CartItemType[])=>{
  return items.reduce((ack:number,item)=>ack + item.amount* item.price, 0)
}
```